# AndroidGms.Maps.MapFragment to Android.Views.View

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to add a map on the MvxFragment, but getting the following error

> There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'AndroidGms.Maps.MapFragment' to 'Android.Views.View'

**xml**

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width ="match_parent"
   android:layout_height ="match_parent"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**View.cs**

```
public class MapView : MvxFragment<MapViewModel>, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private View view;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MapView, null);
        SetUpMap();
        return view;
     }

     private void SetUpMap()
     {
       if (mMap == null)
        {
         // the error appears here
         view.FindViewById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
      }
 }
```

[image]

---

**Update :**

If I either use `FragmentManager` or `ChildFragmentManager`, then I am getting the following error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fragment is not a View, hence you cannot use the `FindViewById` method. What then, how do you find your Fragment then?

You need to use the `FragmentManager` or `ChildFragmentManager` (I will let you figure out which one to use in what case).

Then you can call `FindFragmentById` to get your Fragment on a FragmentManager:

```
var mapFragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);
```

Now you should be able to call `GetMapAsync` on your `MapFragment` to get the `GoogleMap`.

EDIT:

Seems like ChildFragmentManager doesn't have the generic version of FindFragmentById, you can do this instead:

```
var mapFragment = ChildFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map).JavaCast<MapFragment>();
```

Comment: Use an emulator with Play Services

Comment: I have installed the APK on the device, this error message does not exist but I cannot able to see the map, I only see google icon at the left bottom. What would be the problem?